# Probability of a patient receiving new treatment

Tags: probability

*Five percent of patients suffering from a certain disease are selected to undergo a new treatment that is believed to increase the recovery rate from $30$ percent to $50$ percent. A person is randomly selected from these patients after the completion of the treatment and is found to have recovered. What is the probability that the patient received the new treatment?*

***What I attempted:-***  Let us define the events

$E$= The event that the selected patient received the new treatment
$\overline{E}$= The patient didn't receive the treatment 
$A$= The patient has been recovered

We are required to find $P(E|A)$. Here $P(E)=0.05$, $P(\overline{E})=0.95$, $P(A|E)=0.50$, and $P(A|\overline{E})=0.30$

Thus, \begin{equation}
\begin{aligned} 
P(E|A)&=\frac{P(E).P(A|E)}{P(E).P(A|E)+P(\overline{E}).P(A|\overline{E})} \\
&=\frac{0.05\times 0.50}{0.05\times 0.50+0.95\times 0.30}\\
&=\frac{5}{62}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Am I correct ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Bayes Theorem is that $P(E|A)$ is $\frac{P(A|E) * P(E)}{P(A)}$ which is exactly what you did.